# How can i remove a ec2_key from an instance with ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, key-pair

I have an ec2 key pair which was used to provision an AMI. Now, I want to remove the public key from AMI. With ec2_key, there is an option to provide the region, but i want to delete the key only from the AMI instance. Is there a way by which I can achieve this ?

````
- name: Remove SSH key
  ec2_key:
     name: "{{ ec2_key_name  }}"
     state: absent
     instance_ids: {{}} ```
````

Comment: An AMI Instance would be the instance created from an AMI and it should be running in an AWS region. So it seems you can provide region while deleting it. If that's not the case, could you please explain the question in a little more detail?

Comment: I do not want the key for the region but only for a particular instance. How can we achieve that  ?

Answer (score 0):

Have deleted the key from an ec2 instance with authorized_key module :

```
authorized_key:
   user: ubuntu
   state: absent
   key : "{{ ssh_public_key }}"
```